# Using subprocess in Python how do I run 'openvpn' as administrator?

Tags: python, subprocess, administrator

I can run openvpn with default permissions:

```
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
args = 'E:\\OpenVPN\\bin\\openvpn-gui.exe --connect ' + server + '.udp.ovpn'
subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL, shell=False)
```

How do I change this to ensure it runs as administrator?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`runas` utility](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) – untested, the quoting may need some work:

```py
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
command = 'E:\\OpenVPN\\bin\\openvpn-gui.exe --connect ' + server + '.udp.ovpn'
runas_command = 'runas /user:Administrator "%s"' % command
subprocess.Popen(runas_command, stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL, shell=False)
```

If `runas` doesn't work, [`psexec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) probably will.